# Use python 3.8 instead of 3.6 on elementary OS (or Ubuntu)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, elementary-os

I recently started using elementary OS. It's based on Ubuntu.
During installation it installs python 3.6.

I installed python 3.8 manually by installing the following packages: `python3.8`, `python3.8-dev`, `python3.8-minimal`, `python3.8-venv`.
I also updated the link to the python binary with:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3
```

After this a couple of things stopped working.
For example when I tried to execute a non-existing command it didn't print the error message that it cannot found the command, but it displayed a python stack trace. That one I solved with:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
sudo ln -s apt_inst.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_inst.so
```

As you can see the python error was because it couldn't find the compiled binaries for the apt module.

So this issue was solved, but there are a couple of similar ones, and none of them can be solved this way, as the module binary is not compatible with python 3.8.

Is it possible to remove python 3.6 completely and override it with 3.8 so that the module binaries also get updated? Or can python 3.8 and 3.6 coexist? I would be fine with the `/usr/bin/python3` link pointing to python 3.6 and I would manually execute `/usr/bin/python3.8` or create a different alias or link for it. However when I print out the `sys.path` with `/usr/bin/python3.8` I get this:

```
/usr/lib/python38.zip
/usr/lib/python3.8
/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload
/home/{username}/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

The trouble is with the last one. That's where the modules are with the 3.6 compatible so files. Can I somehow force python 3.8 to completely ignore the last module search path *(without always stating sys.path.remove in my scripts)* ?

Comment: Use a virtual environment to run code using your Python 3.8 installation; leave the system-installed version alone. If possible, revert `/usr/bin/python3` to whatever it was before, as well as your changes to `apt_pkg.so` and `apt_inst.so`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you undo your symlink overwriting your systemwide version of Python 3. As you have found, replacing the `python3` executable might create some problems, as it is used under the hood.

In general, you should leave your system `python[3]` installation alone for this reason and it is common to use [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html). This can be done as follows (assuming you are in some project directory):

```
python3.8 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

The first command will create a virtual environment ('venv') in the directory `venv`. The second command will 'activate': now `python` (and in this case, `python3` and `python3.8`) all refer to your original `python3.8` in the context of this shell. You will have to repeat this if you launch a new shell.

This will also allow you to [install packages using `pip`](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) without cluttering your system installation. The use of virtual environments and pip is an incredibly common workflow in the Python development world.

In terms of shell and 'global' Python management, you can also use [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage your Python versions and what is available in the shell. `pyenv` is quite nice if you want to run a particular version of `python`, say `3.8.0` but not `3.8.1`.

Comment: Thanks. How did I not know about this before? :) This is great.